# Reflection Type Adapt

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have a problem with reflection, basically i need to call a method of Class like this:

```
public Int32 addNumer (Int32 a, Int32 b)
{
    return (a+b);
}
```

And i need to call it with Reflection, because i receive this input from "external" C#
software and i need to evaluate witch method i need to call.

The problem is that as Input i have 2 object passed by "prompt command line",
o I have converted it in Byte:

```
Byte a = 10;
Byte b = 10;
```

So, when i perform Refection i see an error "cannot find method addNumber"
because the method with 2 byte in input was not found. I think that it expected
2 Int32 and not 2 Byte.

How i can resolve it?

D.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
Object result_object = target_class.InvokeMember(method, 
                           BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, target_object, 
                           args_values, null, null, args_names);
```

**UPDATE 2:**
i can't CAST to Int32 because i receive this call from a EXE file:

```
MyProjectPrompt.exe Namespace.Class.Method param1 param2
```

Example:

```
MyProjectPrompt.exe It.Company.Math.Add 10 10
```

**SOLUTION**

```
ParameterInfo[] listaParametr = method_to_invoke.GetParameters();

ParameterInfo infoParam;
for(Int32 va=0;va<listaParametr.Length;va++)
{
    infoParam = listaParametr[va];

    for(Int32 va2=0;va2<args_values.Length;va2++)
    {
        if(args_names[va2]==infoParam.Name)
        {
            args_values[va2] = Convert.ChangeType(args_values[va2], 
                                                  infoParam.ParameterType);                        
        }
    }
}
```

Basically for EVERY Param to pass, i cast it.
After that i pass it dynamically:

```
Object result_object = target_class.InvokeMember(method, 
                           BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, target_object, 
                           args_values, null, null, args_names);
```

Comment: Add the code where you use reflection to find the method.

Comment: So you don't know the name of `addNumber` and want to find it given that it could be called with 2 bytes?

Comment: If the above is Yes, then try getting a list of all methods with 2 identical parameters, then filtering based on `IsAssignableFrom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) to change your original value to a type accepted by the method. It'll throw an exception if no suitable conversion can be found.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public class Test1
{
    public Int32 addNumer (Int32 a, Int32 b)
    {
         return (a+b);
    }
}


static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Byte a = 10;
    Byte b = 20;

    object test = new Test1();

    //note how I cast a and b to int 
    //int is an alias to Int32

    typeof(Test1).GetMethod("addNumber").Invoke(test, 
                          new object[] { (int)a, (int)b }); 
}
```

Comment: i can't do that, because i have dinamically called getMethod and i don't know his params typed.

Comment: You do know the name of the function you want to call?